# mysql update on same table, get cumulative figures

Tags: mysql, updates

I have a MySQL table with a row for each financial year, and with columns called Profit and CProfit. 
I want to accumulate the profit over the years by applying adding this year's profit to last year's cumulative profit.

My statements in a MySQL stored procedure is:

```
UPDATE GAME_DETAIL X JOIN GAME_DETAIL Y 
USING (GAME_ID, PLAYER_NO, PRODUCT_NO) 
SET X.CPROFIT=X.PROFIT+Y.CPROFIT 
WHERE X.GAME_ID=ZGAME AND X.YEAR = CY AND X.YEAR=Y.YEAR-1;
```

When I run the above statement, it keep returning NULL values, i.e. it refuses to add up the two figures.

Appreciate your advice. Thanks. 
Kin

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET. Also, and it's just a personal thing, avoid USING - it gets confUSING!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is most easily written as a correlated subquery:

```
update game_detail gd
    set gd.cprofit = (select sum(profit)
                      from game_detail gd2
                      where gd2.game_id = gd.game_id and
                            gd2.year <= gd.year
                     );
```

The reason your version doesn't work is because `update` is an atomic operation.  The `update` takes effect on all rows at the same time, so the "next" row doesn't see the calculated value of the "current" row when it is being updated.